# Unable to catch async/await Task exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a fire and forget method(its there for legacy purpose),

```
BackgroundWorker.Run(() => {
          // my code here that throws an error                         
});
```

I don't wanna await `BackgroundWorker.Run`. Here is my class,

```
public class BackgroundWorker
{        
    public static Task Run(Action action)
    {
        return new IISBackgroundTask().DoWorkAsync(action);
    }
    class IISBackgroundTask : IRegisteredObject
    {
        public IISBackgroundTask()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
        }            
        void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            if (_task.IsCompleted || _task.IsCanceled || _task.IsFaulted || immediate)
            {
                HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
            }
        }
        public async Task DoWorkAsync(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                _task =  Task.Run(action);
                await _task;
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                // Log exceptions
                foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Logger.Log(innerEx);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(ex);
            }
        }

        private Task _task;
    }
}
```

I am unable to catch exception.

**Update:** If I add await at `BackgroundWorker.Run` then it will work but I wanna fire and forget.

Comment: Which kind of exception, could you please post the exception info?

Comment: @KimKulling Null exception at `// my code here that throws an error  `

Comment: "Fire and **forget**" literally *means* "I don't care about exceptions".

Comment: @StephenCleary I mean to let my client get the response asap and in the backgroiund I can run some code. I know your library as well but for now I wanna know why its not working.

Comment: The code in the question will catch exceptions thrown from `action`. Unless you're using `async void`, that will work.

Comment: Just try it your self it's not catching

Answer (score 1):

For now I have fixed it using,

```
        public void DoWork(Action action)
        {
            _task = Task.Run(() => 
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                }
                catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        Logger.Log(innerEx);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Log(ex);
                }
            });
        }
```